# mdadm RAID-1 extremly slow on Debian Squeeze

Tags: mdadm

Today I has started experiencing troubles with my php/web server.

I've a lot of segfaults messages in php-fpm logs. At first I thought it was problems with versions incompatibility of may be some php modules, but `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` also  randomly reported about `Segmentation faulty tree` etc.

At the moment I discovered extremely low speed of my hard drives.

I have no idea why is the hdd speed is **less than 5 MB/s**...

Some tech details:

```
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# hdparm -t /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   8 MB in  3.01 seconds =   2.65 MB/sec
```

Before this moment everything worked fine (about may be 1 year).

I'm using mdadm RAID-1 and I tried to change bitmap option (as said [in tip #5](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html)) and even remove one HDD and add it again - it didn't help.

mdadm output:

```
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Fri Oct 26 22:39:25 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 488386496 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 488386496 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Apr 12 14:06:35 2014
          State : clean, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

 Rebuild Status : 9% complete

           UUID : 157b06cd:e27f8486:c3ede18e:95b605a2 (local to host portex)
         Events : 0.2874

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       16        0      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdb
       1       8        0        1      active sync   /dev/sda
```

hdparm output:

```
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# hdparm -t /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   6 MB in  3.81 seconds =   1.58 MB/sec
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# hdparm -t /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   6 MB in  7.36 seconds = 834.54 kB/sec
```

hdparm -i output:

```
 root@portex:/var/log/fsck# hdparm -i /dev/sda

 /dev/sda:

 Model=ST500DM002-1BD142, FwRev=KC45, SerialNo=Z3T3TKNH
 Config={ HardSect NotMFM HdSw>15uSec Fixed DTR>10Mbs RotSpdTol>.5% }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=4
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=16384kB, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=16
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=976773168
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
 PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
 DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2
 UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6
 AdvancedPM=no WriteCache=enabled
 Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-4,5,6,7

 * signifies the current active mode
```

OS version:

```
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.9
```

**UPDATE**

iostat output:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.85    0.00   19.05    0.00    0.00   75.09

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda              51.00     0.00   67.00    0.50     7.31     0.00   221.93     0.94   13.60   1.07   7.20
sdb               0.00    50.00    0.00   63.00     0.00     6.66   216.44     0.21    2.95   0.83   5.20
md0               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

/proc/mdstat output:

```
root@portex:/var/log/fsck# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb[2] sda[1]
      488386496 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      [===========>.........]  recovery = 55.8% (272962432/488386496) finish=409.8min speed=8758K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: As you can see in the `mdadm` output the mirror is trying to resync itself because you pulled a drive.  Until that 9% reaches 100% you aren't going to get peak performance regardless of any other issues there may be.  I wouldn't do a thing to try and fix it until that's done.

Comment: I susepct yoonix is right in what (s)he writes above.  Could you add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` to your answer, though?

Comment: @yoonix I added iostat output, and we can see that sda is syncing to sdb, but the speed is suspicious to me - 7Mb for writing...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I discovered the hard way (and by speaking to the manufacturer) that the problem is the drives you are using - Barracuda (consumer grade) drives - don't play well with RAID in some motherboards (in my case an HP 1u system).  Although highly skeptical I replaced my Barracuda drives with server class (Constellation) drives and this fixed the problem.    I do note that this only affects some hardware - I have Intel 1u servers which work just fine.

(I am still at a loss why software raid should behave this way, it does not seem intuitive - almost like the hardware was deliberately designed to be crippled  - but Constellation drives are not that much more expensive !)